# setVolume method AudioPlayer is not working - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, media-player

The setVolume method of the audio player is not working. For example: When I set the volume value to 0, it should mute the volume, right? but I can still hear the volume despite setting the volume to 0

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

void playMusic() async {
await audioPlayer.setVolume(0); // Not working
audioPlayer.play(url); // I can still hear the volume despite setting the volume value to zero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
bool isPlaying = false;
double _value = 0.0;
String url = '';
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
  setState(() {
    isPlaying = state == PlayerState.playing;
  });
});

audioPlayer.setVolume(_value);
}
```

I am then updating the value of volume by slider value.